# Wording and answer of algebra for GRE

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, gre-exam

I am studying for [GRE](http://www.ets.org/gre) and have been stumped by

1. The question
2. The answer

#### Question:

When the positive integer n is divided by 45, the remainder is 18. Which of the following must be a divisor of n?

#### Choices

a) 11

b) 9

c) 7

d) 6

e) 4

Are they asking what is `k`, where `n/45 = k` ? Because I think divisor is something that divides `n`, i.e. `n/k = 45`

But then their explanation is more confusing

#### Explanation

> The given information tells you that n can be expressed in the form n
>   = 45k + 18, where k can be any nonnegative integer.
>
> Consider how the divisors of 45 and 18 may be related to the divisors
>   of n.

But I am not understanding what this has to do with `k`.

> Every common divisor of 45 and 18 is also a divisor of any sum of
>   multiples of 45 and 18, like 45k + 18.

But what does this have to do with `k`?

> So any common divisor of 45 and 18 is also a divisor of n. Of all the
>   answer choices given, only 9 is a common divisor of 45 and 18. Thus
>   the correct answer is Choice B.

Why must there be a common divisor o 45 and 18. I thought 18 was the remainder of n/45 = k.

So are they saying k = 9? I am really really confused. I tried asking someone who is good at math, and he couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The are asking for the divisor. What can $n$ be divided by?
As $n = 45k + 18 = 9(5k+2)$, what do you think $n$ can be divided by?

Comment: That is very interesting ..... `What do you think n can be divided by` is really the question they were asking. This part of GRE exam is `Quantitative Analysis` -  wording was confusing, but now you made it understandable. And the math explanation helps, because I was going in circles yesterday, trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $n=45k+18$, for some $k$. Thus, immediately, $9$ is a divisor of $n$, as it divides both $45$ and $18$.

Can we dismiss all other cases?

(a) $n=18$ is not divisible by $11$
(c) $n=18$ is not divisible by $7$
(d) $n=63$ is not divisible by $6$
(e) $n=18$ is not divisible by $4$